# How to get uploaded file size in django

Tags: django, upload, filesize

I am uploading a zip file through my form. How I can get the file size i.e in KB / MB  so I can display it in my template.

Comment: This is this may get you, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has a builti [**`|filesizeformat`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filesizeformat), you can thus use this with:

```
{{ file.size|filesizeformat }}
```

as the documentation says, this will:

> Formats the value like a ‘human-readable’ file size (i.e. `'13 KB'`, `'4.1 MB'`, `'102 bytes'`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by using this custom template tag: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1866/

After then use it like this in your template:

```
{% load sizify  %}

{{ yourFile.size|sizify }}
```

The file size will then be shown in a human readable format (kb, Mb, Gb)

Comment: thanks, i add the template tag but I am getting this error: 'sizify' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of ....

Comment: Put sizify.py inside app_name/templatetags and make sure you restart the Django development server (or ensure it restarted itself) every time you modify template tags. If the server does not restart, Django won't register the tags.